# TypeScript: pass generic type as parameter in generic class

Tags: generics, typescript

**TypeScript:** 
I have a method in the DataProvider class with a method getTableData:

```
public static getTableData<T extends DataObject>(type: { new(): T}): Array<T> { ... }
```

this works perfectly when I code:

```
let speakers = DataProvider.getTableData(Speaker);  // where Speaker is a class
```

now I want to call this from a generic Class:

```
export class ViewModelBase<T extends DataObject> {   
  public getData(): Array<T> {
    return <T[]> DataProvider.getTableData(T);
  }
}
```

Now I get a *Cannot find name 'T'* error for the T parameter I pass to getTableData. How should getTableData be called?

**update**:
With the help of @Paleo I came up this:

```
export class ViewModelBase<T extends DataObject> {   

  constructor(private dataObjectClass: { new(): T}){}

  public getTableData(): Array<T> {
    return <T[]> DataProvider.getTableData<T>(this.dataObjectClass);
  }
}
```

the thing is that although I have already told in:
`class SpeakerViewModel extends ViewModelBase<Speaker> { ... }` 
that I want it to be a ViewModel for `Speaker` I still have the instantiate the `SpeakerViewModel` like:

`let vm = new SpeakerViewModel(Speaker);`

although I have already told it is all about `Speaker`. I guess I still don't fully understand this.

Comment: In `DataProvider.getTableData(T)`, the parameter `T` is defined nowhere.

Comment: _"that I want it to be a ViewModel for Speaker I still have the instantiate the SpeakerViewModel like:`let vm = new SpeakerViewModel(Speaker);`"_ sorry, I am confused. Can you rephrase that?  What is the code you want to omit?

Comment: I'm not sure what changed, but I was only able to get this to work with the parameter signature like `{ new(...args:  any[]): T }`.  I have a suspicion that it's because my class constructor had parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Generics are just metadata. They cannot be used as parameters when calling a function. Maybe you need something like this:

```
export class ViewModelBase<T extends DataObject> {
  constructor(private Cl: {new(): T}) {
  }
  public getData(): Array<T> {
    return DataProvider.getTableData<T>(this.Cl);
  }
}
```

Comment: almost but your comment made me figure what I actually needed: `constructor(private Cl: { new(): T})...`. Thanks!

Comment: @BroncoOostermeyer OK. I edited to fix the code for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this would help:

```
export abstract class BaseEntity {
  public static from<T extends BaseEntity>(c: new() => T, data: any): T {
    return Object.assign(new c(), data)
  }
  public static first<T extends BaseEntity>(c: new() => T, data) {
    if (data.rows.length > 0) {
      let item = data.rows.item(0);
      return BaseEntity.from(c, item);
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

This class can be extended by others so you could call methods on the base class or on its subclasses.

For instance:

```
return Product.first(Product, data);
```

Or:

```
return BaseEntity.first(Product, data);
```

See how `from()` method is called from inside `first()`

Answer (score -2):

How about defining a base type and extending it? Then your function could expect the base type, and you could call it with the extended type. e.g:

```
export interface BaseData {
  key: object
}
```

Then:

```
import { BaseData } from 'baseDataFile'

export interface DerivedData extends BaseData {
  key: someObjectType
}
```

Now:

```
import { BaseData } from 'baseDataFile'

export const someFunc = (props: BaseData) => {
    // do some stuff
    return something 
}
```

Finally:

```
import { DerivedData } from 'derivedDataFile'

const myData: DerivedData = something as DerivedData
const myNewData = someFunc(myData)
```